# Why do I get different random numbers with the same seed?

Tags: python, numpy, random-seed

I am using the numpy random number generator with the following MWE:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(40)
print(np.random.randint(-3, 4))
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=40)
print(rng.integers(-3, 4))
```

This outputs:

```
3
0
```

Why are the outputs different?

Comment: They are different random generators, that's the point of the new random API. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61676156/how-to-use-the-new-numpy-random-number-generator is closest post I can find now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`numpy.random.randint` and `numpy.random.seed` use the old random API, with an entirely different implementation under the hood. `numpy.random.default_rng` creates a Generator object, which is the new API.

The two APIs are effectively two entirely separate RNG libraries that happen to live in the same namespace. Output isn't expected to match, even with the same seed.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, `numpy` provides still access to legacy generators through `np.random.RandomState`. The latter can be use to get exactly the same result using the new object-oriented random API than the old global state based API. Its documentation can be found [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/legacy.html):

```py
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(40)

print(np.random.randint(-3, 4))

rng = np.random.RandomState(40)
print(rng.randint(-3, 4))
```

However, it does not expose exactly the same user API as the new `Generator` class, and no compatibility layer between the old and the new API is provided.

Another, more hacky option, is to initialize `Generator` with the same generator as the one used by the old global state under the hood:

```py
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(40)

print(np.random.rand(4))

mt19937 = np.random.MT19937()
np.random.seed(40)
mt19937.state = np.random.rand.__self__.get_state()
rng = np.random.Generator(mt19937)
print(rng.random(4))
```

Then, it will give you the same result in most cases, but there is no guarantee for that ! Typically, `np.random.rand` is the same as `rng.random`, but `np.random.randint` is different from `rng.integers` because the internal sampling algorithm is different.

Comment: `numpy.random.RandomState` is not a compatibility layer. It's just an ordinary part of the old API. It was always there, even before the new API went in. (That's why it's not, you know, *compatible* with the new API, like a compatibility layer would be.)

Comment: @user2357112 Yes you are right ! I updated my answer accordingly.