# Duplicate randoms numbers from legacy np.random.rand using the new np.random.Generator

Tags: python, numpy, random

I'm looking to replicate the generation of random numbers with uniform distribution provided by the legacy np.random.rand using the modern np.random.Generator in NumPy.

What's the best approach to achieve this efficiently, and are there any specific considerations or techniques to maintain consistency between the two methods?

Here are examples using both approaches:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import Generator, MT19937

# Using legacy np.random.rand
np.random.seed(100)
x1 = np.random.rand(5)
print("x1:", x1)

# Using np.random.Generator
rng = Generator(MT19937(100))
x2 = rng.random(size=(5,))
print("x2:", x2)
```

Output:

```
x1: [0.54340494 0.27836939 0.42451759 0.84477613 0.00471886]
x2: [0.98132524 0.73361268 0.67713615 0.97430929 0.04939542]
```

Comment: Can't - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77799809/why-do-i-get-different-random-numbers-with-the-same-seed#77799832

Comment: I concur, it cannot be done unless you do manual wrapper around old code

Comment: Actually, `numpy` offers a compatibility layer that can be use to get exactly the same result using the new object-oriented random API than the old global state based API. The documentation can be found [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/legacy.html).

Comment: All it requires is using `RandomState` class instead of `Generator` (`rng = np.random.RandomState(100)`). It exposes basically the same user API as `Generator`, with a few exceptions (eg `integers` is not available).

Comment: Super! it worked. So the trick is to use the legacy seeding algorithm instead of the new `SeedSequence`. Thank you, @duburcqa